# Mikrotik rb951 Reset Counters for All Users Weekly

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

I bought a [Mikrotik rb951](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:TOCdoes) [access point](https://mikrotik.com/product/RB951-2n) solely to limit my family from using all the download allowance in the Internet package from our ISP before the end of the month.

I created users in the hotspot for each device in the house and limited their download depending on how much each person needs.

What I want to know is how I can reset all counters automatically daily or weekly for each person, or for all users if it can't be done on a user-by-user basis?

Comment: The OS manual https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:TOCdoes not show any way to.  DD-WRT https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/ and Tomato https://tomato.groov.pl/?page_id=69 are not known to work on a Microtik but OpenWRT does show some information on it https://openwrt.org/toh/mikrotik/rb951g_2hnd?s[]=mikrotik&s[]=rb951  Suggest you also ask in https://forum.mikrotik.com/

Comment: I figured it out, I just went to the scheduler in Winbox and added this script

/ip hotsport user reset-counters

and from the intervals, you can run it hourly, daily, weekly or even monthly depending on the amount of hours you put in their.

Comment: Excellent! I hope you will create an Answer to share your findings with other Mikrotik users, for Comments are transient and will not be preserved,, whereas Answers will be preserved. I have also requested the question be reopened after I clarified your intent.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I just went to the scheduler in Winbox and added this script, which I found here https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=36147

```
/ip hotspot user reset-counters
```

and from the intervals, you can run it hourly, daily, weekly or even monthly depending on the number of hours you put in there.

Edit:

You can also reset counters for individual users at different intervals by scheduling this script for each one with their username

```
/ip hotspot user reset-counters [find name="username"]
```